# What is the optimal string format for converting to an array?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm producing a string with GROUP_CONCAT in MySQL.

There are 2 columns I need to select for each row being id and name, how should I format the string in the query so I can produce an array that couples the ids and names in PHP at optimal speed?

For example (my attempt):
GROUP_CONCAT producing

```
{"id":1,"name":"python"},{"id":2,"name":"ruby"}
```

Then convert this to an array in PHP.

Comment: Just a mysql_fetch_array didn't help you?

Comment: write your query and table structure, maybe there is better way than group_concat

Comment: @safarov no there isn't a better way, tags will be one column and the remaining columns will be the question details.

Comment: Maybe you can post your SQL query so we can help you find a better way? Generating JSON by hand is not a good idea at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why you are attempting this. But this query should work

```
SELECT * FROM `yourtable` GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT('{"id":"',id,'","name":"',name,'"}') 
    separator ',')
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your `GROUP_CONCAT()` producing a JSON string? In that case, `json_decode($string, true)` (json_decode() on [PHP docs](http://ar.php.net/json_decode)) will do the thing.

But that will not be faster than doing it like The Jumping Frog suggested above. `mysql_fetch_array()` will parse the string for you (use `MYSQL_NUM` to avoid extra overhead) and you'll also avoid the MySQL extra time on the `GROUP_CONCAT()`;

If you just want to store some JSON data on the DB (this will complicate future searches and indexing, but is a good choice sometimes when you don't want to create a ton of DB fields, Wordpress does it all the time), you can use `json_encode()` before storing and `json_decode()` to retrieve the original array/object for that purpose. You can also use PHP `serialize()` and `unserialize()`, but I think JSON is preferable because you mentioned you where using Javascript.

Comment: Generating JSON in a mysql query is a fool's errand. Think SQL injection, but for JSON instead. Best to fetch raw data from MySQL and then do the manipulation/encoding in PHP.

Comment: No. doing a regular `select id, name from ...` query and then building that into a PHP array, then json_encoding that would be FAR more reliable.

Comment: @Marc B Tag names are sanitised by the way. How is there a vulnerability to injection?

Comment: Someone has suggested this is not a bad idea: http://www.thomasfrank.se/mysql_to_json.html. Thoughts?

Comment: @amia: just because it's coming OUT of a database doesn't mean you can't inject yourself. what if one of those names was `John "MadDog" Hall`? You've now pasted an unbalanced quote into the JSON and broken the entire string.

Comment: @Marc B I see, but wouldn't constraining tag names to be JSON safe characters make it secure?

Comment: If you can guarantee that nothing 'bad' will EVER get into the database, then sure. But that's not a good way to go.

Comment: @Marc B Isn't that a principle of databases - don't let bad things in? Or do you mean don't make extra effort to stop bad stuff for different domains HTML, JSON etc when handling database input?

Comment: you always have to let bad stuff in. consider a user whose name is `O'Brien`. That quote is an injection/syntax error waiting to happen, but you don't force the user to change their name because your code can't handle it. 'Bad' can always be stored in a DB. That's why we have escaping/parameterized queries. If you store your data 'ready' for one target environment (say, HTML), then if you need to use that data in another environment (say, JSON), you now have to UNDO your html sanitization. Always store data 'raw' (but safely) and convert as needed upon retrieval.

Comment: @Marc B So as long as I store the JSON safely (there's probably a nice  php json-string escape function) shouldn't John "MadDog" Hall be safe? I'd just have to unescape it in php again or even javascript?

Comment: @Marc B Or would SQL escaping conflict with it?

Comment: as long as the escapes actually make it into the database, then yeah. But then you're storing stuff in json- or sql- escaped form, and are subject to double transformations yet again.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this -

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1', 'user', 'pass');
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT some_field, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('::', id, name) SEPARATOR '||') AS grp
                      FROM `table`
                      GROUP BY some_field");
$stmt->execute();

while($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
    foreach(explode('||', $row->grp) as $pair) {
        $tmp = explode('::', $pair);
        $array[$row->some_field][$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
    }
}
print_r($array);
```

As pointed out by safarov you need to be aware of the group_concat_max_len limitation.